# Extract timestamp from uuid1

Tags: php, timestamp, uuid

I am sorry for this pretty basic topic but I am not able to found a proper answer after multiple Google search

I got a uuid1 and would like to extract the timestamp contain in it, this seems to be 100% possible because this website is giving me the right answer : https://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen when I try with ce53f406-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3

I didn't find any easy solution after my research... There is no basic solution to extract this timestamp ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question popped up on my radar, since it is tagged with "php." If you're looking for a PHP solution to get the timestamp out of a version 1 UUID, you can use the [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) library to parse UUIDs. (It's my library, so I'm a bit biased.)

Install the library using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

```
composer require ramsey/uuid
```

And then you can do things like this to get a [PHP DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) object from the UUID:

```
$myUuid = 'ce53f406-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3';

$uuid = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::fromString($myUuid);

echo 'UUID timestamp (60-bit integer): ' . $uuid->getTimestamp() . "\n";
echo 'Formatted date/time: ' . $uuid->getDateTime()->format('r') . "\n";
echo 'Unix timestamp: ' . $uuid->getDateTime()->getTimestamp() . "\n";
```

This example will print out something that looks like:

```
UUID timestamp (60-bit integer): 136967953640059910
Formatted date/time: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 17:22:44 +0000
Unix timestamp: 1477502564
```

Answer (score 3):

Observe the UUID you provided:

```
ce53f406-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
```

The first octave is `ce53f406`. This is hexadecimal number and has an unit of 100 nano second. Meaning, this part will get incremented by 1 in every 100 nano second interval. The maximum number this octave can have is `ffffffff`. Once `ffffffff` is reached the left most octave will reset to 0, while the next octave (`9ba0`) increments by 1 and so on. Therefore in every 100 nano second interval UUID would get generated like this:

```
ce53f406-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
ce53f407-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
ce53f408-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
ce53f409-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
ce53f40a-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
.
.
.
fffffffd-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
fffffffe-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
ffffffff-9ba0-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
00000000-9ba1-11e6-a6e8-e715bd508dc3
```

Now, you know the logic and if you know the timestamp of one UUID you should be able to get another by comparing.

Comment: Sorry for being so long to give you the point for this very good answer ;)
Thank's for the exemple !